# Java using scanner input a txt to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{
   public static final int SIZE = 30;
   public static final int DUE_DATE = 15;
   public static final int TASK_NUMBER = 30;
   public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter input file: ");
      String inputCompletionName = console.next();

      boolean[][] completion = new boolean[TASK_NUMBER][SIZE];
      File inputCompletion = new File(inputCompletionName);
      Scanner in = new Scanner(inputCompletion);
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
         for(i = 0; i < TASK_NUMBER; i++){
            while(in.hasNextBoolean()){         
               boolean input = in.nextBoolean();
               completion[i][j] = input;
            }
            System.out.println(completion[i][j]);
         }

      }
   }
```

I tried this code. My input is some boolean value but the output only have first element. Really don't know how to fix this.

My input file is just some random boolean values like this.

true
false
true
false
true

But the output only shows the first element.

Comment: Show the file you are reading from.

Comment: Hi Zhifan. Welcome to Posting on Stack Overflow. While code is important,  can you please state precisely what input and output is required.  The statement "output only have first element" does not tell me what output you are expecting. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My input file is like this.


true
false
true
false
true

But the output only shows the first element true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
while(in.hasNextBoolean()) { 
     boolean input = in.nextBoolean();
     completion[i][j] = input;
}
```

And that is inside your 2 for loops, so you read your booleans into the same grid cell.

This will work:

```
for(j = 0; j < SIZE && in.hasNextBoolean(); j++){
    for(i = 0; i < TASK_NUMBER && in.hasNextBoolean(); i++){      
        boolean input = in.nextBoolean();
        completion[i][j] = input;
        System.out.println(completion[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: @ZhifanHui I did.